# Why sharepoint tag is present in SO

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

I have seen few questions on SO regarding Sharepoint, and  seen many comments "This question is off topic because it is about sharepoint" go to [sharepoint.stackexchange.com](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/) .

So my question is why sharepoint tag is there to let user choose it ?
 I think either user should be notified about it while choosing tags or Sharepoint Tag should be removed from Tag options in SO.

Feel free to rephrase or edit my question/query .

Comment: I think it's been a mistake by me, They have a notification regarding visitng `sharepoint.stackexchange.com` for **Sharepoint** and **Sharepoint2010** related queries only.

Comment: Stack Overflow is way older than Sharepoint.SE, _some_ Sharepoint questions were on topic on Stack Overflow before Sharepoint.SE came to be. Also, everyone can create any tag they want. A question isn't on-topic just because a related tag exists.

Comment: @Yannis I understand there are many questions on SO before Sharepoint.SE came, but i think SP2013 is something very new, so they should not be on SO if it's so, and what makes a question on-topic if you can elaborate your comment please beacuse in few questions user got downvoted just because that question was on SO not on Sharepoint.stackexchange.

Comment: You can find more details on what's on topic on SO in the help center: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @Yannis Any particular point you want to suggest ?

Comment: I've linked to a specific article @Suraj, give it a quick read. A quick summary would be: If your question is about a _specific programming problem_, then it's probably on-topic. No idea if the SP2013 questions you have in mind would qualify, as you didn't link to them.

Comment: I just asked because i already through that link and i can say questions i am backing up did qualified all rules and specification for a valid question, What i am suggesting is sometimes it confuses peoples as a user i've been through it, i didn't had any idea about Sharepoint.SE and rather than answer i got votes to close and off-topic comments .

Comment: ...and those off topic comments pointed you to the right direction. Now that you know Sharepoint.SE exists, you can post your future SP2013 questions there. The system works.

Comment: Sharepoint. *shudder*. I'm going to go over to Area51 and propose a Lotus Notes stack. Or maybe Baal-worship.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stack Overflow used to be the home to *most* Sharepoint questions before Sharepoint SE was proposed and subsequently created. The catch was, questions about Sharepoint on SO had to be related to programming. Questions on administration and general use really didn't have a good home, so folks took the topic and ran with it.

There's still a *high* degree of overlap when it comes to questions that involve programming. They aren't technically *off* topic on Stack Overflow, and some folks like asking there because they:

- Feel that they'll get an answer faster
- Don't want to create yet another profile to ask a question on a different site that would probably be on topic on the current one
- Have no idea Sharepoint SE exists, or Stack Exchange for that matter. They know about Stack Overflow through searching and see questions about Sharepoint there, so they ask them.

There is a migration path, so questions that would be a better fit on Sharepoint can be sent there, but there's no need to migrate *just* because the question involves Sharepoint if it's otherwise on topic and getting answers.

This type of overlap isn't uncommon with other sites, since the first round of Stack Exchange 2.0 sites were created *mostly* by programmers. Game development questions are often equally on topic for Stack Overflow, but Gamedev SE is not only chocked full of programmers, they're also *game developers*.

Finally, there are still some rather old Sharepoint questions on SO that are more on topic for Sharepoint SE - they're just way too old to migrate in the absence of a reason more compelling than organization and bucketing.

`tl;dr;` - If you're into Sharepoint, Sharepoint SE is a *fine* site for you. If you  have a *programming* question that happens to involve Sharepoint and for some reason don't want to ask it there, it would *probably* be on topic for SO.

Choices are good! :)

Answer (score 0):

I've asked a question on StackOverflow which relates to Sharepoint.

[My question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16069748/1048539) is related to SharePoint but the focus is on the VBA/Outlook side. [Questions referencing VBA on Sharepoint.SE](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/search?q=vba+is%3Aquestion) don't really get at any content which is similar.

Would this have been better on SharePoint.SE? Perhaps, but my experience there has not been overly positive for non-trivial questions. In fact I've had much MUCH better luck posting on the nightmarish MSDN forums for help with SP.